# Unity check total existing object on map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started learning Unity to create a simple games, what I currently have now is game scene that contains playgrounds (all the black spots), with 2 players (red spots and blue dots) [image]. In every play turn, a player will places a red/blue dots in the playgrounds, when there are 3 red or blue dots consecutively in a row or column of the black spots, then that player will win the game [image]. It's similar to the tic tac toe games. But I don't know how could I track this winning conditions since all the black spots and red/blue dots are just Image objects.

```
`    public Image image;
[HideInInspector] public Transform parentAfterDrag;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
    //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    //Debug.Log("Begin Drag");
    parentAfterDrag = transform.parent;
    transform.SetParent(transform.root);
    transform.SetAsLastSibling();
    image.raycastTarget = false;
}
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
    transform.SetParent(parentAfterDrag);
    image.raycastTarget = true;
}`
```

Comment: That has to be the weirdest description of the very well known game ["mills"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_men%27s_morris) I've ever heard :'D .. just that you don't immediately win just because you managed to have three dots in a row ;)

Comment: So ... what exactly is your issue/question?

Comment: What I actually got stuck about how can I check if there is 3 dots with same colours lay on a same column or row (In the second image, 3 blue dots are on a same row, 3 red dots are on a same column) . I'm new to Unity and I don't know which keyword, properties I should use for this case. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how could I track this winning conditions since all the black spots and red/blue dots are just Image objects.

If you mix your view with ur data you can end up having a hard time tracking the actual game state. Keep track of the game state through a matrix or some custom structure and just expose some methods to update the matrix through your UI (dragging and color to black spot/selecting black spot) and update your HUD every time that your structure update, this way your HUD will be just a reflection of your actual game state and both things have a well defines separation.

In this scenario checking for conditions will happen after each move looking for rows/columns that match your structure

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have the above script attached to all red/blue dots. Suppose I have implement a method to track the position of all the dots with the spots, is there any keyword to prevent other dots be dragged inside the taken spots? What I mean that if a red dot placed on a black spot then all other dots could not be placed in that spot

Comment: As you already have scripts on dots, maybe it would be simple if you create a "Slot" abstraction that contains their position and receives these dots, so a Slot without a dot is an empty slot, this will be enough for your drag/drop, then you can have a "Board" abstraction that contains each Slot and check for line/row after each movement

Comment: @LeoTran Simply: you can't do anything useful that involves dragging images around. What you want to do is create a Unity object that displays as the image, but stores information about itself, such as its position on the board. Then, you'd have some layer further up that also knows where they are and can prevent illegal moves.